# Android/Java, how to process a csv file with new lines and comma in some fields?

Tags: java, android

Android/Java, how to process a csv file with new lines and comma in some fields?

for example, there are three fields per record.

```
A, B, "Good morning,
may I get a cup of water?"
C, D, good night.
```

what should I do to correctly parse it and store it to an object arraylist?

if i read the first line, i will miss the second parts of the last fields.

(I tried to add opencsv to the android project, but I got error on build, related to dex..hard to understand..so I am trying to implement the load csv function myself, as I only need to read the file only, but I could not think about the correct logic.)

Answer (score 0):

To read the file and save per record you can use:

```
List<String> content = Files.lines(Paths.get("app.csv")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or if you want to save every field comma delimited use this:

```
List<String> content = Files.lines(Paths.get("app.csv")).collect(Collectors.toList());
List<String> result = new ArrayList();

content.forEach((t) -> {
    for(String s : t.split(",")){
        result.add(s);
    }
});

System.out.println(result);
```

Result:

```
[A,  B,  "Good morning, may I get a cup of water?", C,  D,  good night.]
```

**EDIT**

```
    List<String> content = Files.lines(Paths.get("app.csv")).collect(Collectors.toList());
    List<String> result = new ArrayList();

    StringJoiner tmp = new StringJoiner(" ");
    boolean insideTextFlag = false;

    for(String t : content){
        for (String s : t.split(",")) {
            if(s.contains("\"") || insideTextFlag){

                if(s.contains("\"") && insideTextFlag)
                    insideTextFlag = false;
                else
                    insideTextFlag = true;

                tmp.add(s.trim());                    

                if(!insideTextFlag){
                    result.add(tmp.toString());
                    tmp = new StringJoiner(" ");
                }
            }else{
                result.add(s.trim());
            }
        }
    }

    result.forEach((t) -> {
        System.out.println(t);
    });
```

**OUTPUT**

```
A
B
"Good morning may I get a cup of water?"
C
D
good night.
```

Comment: sorry, it does not work. result.get(2) is  "Good morning.

Comment: @manhon Sorry, you're right.. I edited my answer hope it helps you